# Error persisting a Symfony2 Entity: A new entity was found

Tags: symfony

I have this problem with symfony 2:

"A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\MainEntity#person' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: JOHN DOE CORP. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). "

MainEntity is a normal entity, with a "person" field which is a ManyToOne relation to the People entity. The People entity is a **read only** entity, but I don't know why a new Person is created.

This happens when I update MainEntity through a form. The definition of the form is:

```
    $builder
        ->add('code')
        ->add('type')
        ->add('person', new PeopleType())
        ->add('Save', 'submit');
```

And PeopleType is:

```
    $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('idNumber', 'text', array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('address', new AddressType());
```

As you can see, it's impossible to change the Person field, so I don't understand what's happening here... Any clue, please?

Comment: You have a relation in your entities and you need to add the `cascade={"persist"}` on it... Can you show the code of your entities?

Comment: I can't add the cascade={"persist"} because the People table MUST be a read only table so it's impossible to create new people. Anyway, AFAIK I haven't created any new person...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. I was making a very stupid mistake: I wasn't loading my entity before updating the data, so every time I tried to update the entity I created a new one.